# How to identify customer who make order for 3 and more orders in 7 days. SQL/holistic/redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Summary: I want to get the list of customer who has **3 and more** *orderid* in 7 days. one customer might appear multiple times if the customer fulfills the criteria for each date.

Table name : T1

| customerid | orderid | createdat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1B3 | vds34rve4-3f | 1/1/2021 |
| AA2B | hvdhkc767-s3d | 1/1/2021 |
| EA986 | bckd33rfvfbvdf | 1/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | jdbjkvshb3rdec | 1/1/2021 |
| SFK3 | bhabsd-bbc83ccs | 2/1/2021 |
| AA2B | hcbadcbsbc7cd | 3/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | hjjac73an83-3fc | 7/1/2021 |
| DEH32 | gdyafjk-24vfd | 7/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | jkhbdj434jcbjke | 7/1/2021 |
| AA2B | jkkcbjq90ksnc | 8/1/2021 |
| AA2B | cjbugd3ahsddka | 8/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | kbcq7w69ufj4t4 | 9/1/2021 |
| SFK3 | bcdubi7wklcna8 | 9/1/2021 |
| EA986 | cbyatea4jwndns | 9/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | biqbdepaljkcl9 | 9/1/2021 |
| AA2B | nuqya8wownd2ln2 | 9/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | ndkuq2uowmdlqn | 9/1/2021 |

expected Output:

| customerid | startdate | enddate | count_orderid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1B3 | 1/1/2021 | 7/1/2021 | 4 |
| Aa2B | 3/1/2021 | 9/1/2021 | 4 |
| A1B3 | 7/1/2021 | 9/1/2021 | 5 |

my current solution is

```
WITH daily_count_order AS (
   SELECT customerid, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', createdat) AS startdate, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', DATEADD(DAY, 6, createdat)) AS enddate,
    COUNT(orderid) AS count_order, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY linkdate ASC) AS rows
  FROM T1
  GROUP BY userid, startdate, enddate
)
```

I don't know to transform the logic regarding the criteria(3 and more orderid in 7 days into sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lead()` for this . . . but getting the count is harder.  Start with the dates where this condition is true:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(createdat, 2) over (partition by customerid order by createdat) as date_2
      from t
     ) t
where date_2 < createdat + interval '7 day';
```

If you really need the count, then one method is a self-join:

```
select t.customerid, t.createdat, count(*)
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.customerid = t.customerid and
        t2.createdat >= t.createdat and
        t2.createdat < t.createdat + interval '7 day'
group by t.customerid, t.createdat
having count(*) >= 3;
```